# Prevent View Disappearing in splitview When User Edits Pending Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a universal master-detail application where I present the master
and detail views side by side on an iPad in both orientations. When a
user makes changes in the detail view on an iPhone I can easily detect
changes and present an alert asking if they want to save the changes or
lose them (CoreData). On an iPad, there is no prohibition against simply clicking
in the master list thereby losing the edits.

I have placed a function in the DetailViewController viewWillDisappear
(for iPad) that raises an alert, but the compiler tells me that it does
not like the presentation of a view on a non-connected view.

Console message: Presenting view controllers on detached view
controllers is discouraged <>.

Is there a more appropriate way to handle this? Swift 3, iOS 10, Xcode 8.2.1

```
var hasChanged //set to true whenever edits are made

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if UIDevice.current.model == "iPad" {
        if hasChanged {
            print("hasChanged (should be true) is: \(hasChanged)")
            cancelUnsavedEdits()
        }//if hasChanged
    }//if ipad

}//viewWillDisappear

func cancelUnsavedEdits() {

    if hasChanged {

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Edits", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)

            let editRecordButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.edit, target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.editThisRecord))
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editRecordButton

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

            //need to remove the edits - refresh the original page
            self.configureView()

        }))//addAction block

        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Edits", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()
            self.saveTheEditedRecord()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)
        }))//addAction block

        //ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))

        //try this - for -ipad add code in handler to reopen the fields for editing if the cancel of the cancel is chosen
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (whatever) in
            self.makeEntryFieldsEnabledYES()
            let cancelItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.cancelUnsavedEdits))
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItemButton
        }))
        //try above

        self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()

        //for ipad
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)
    }//if hasChanged

    //for ipad
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

}//cancelUnsavedEdits
```

Comment: I had this problem with a third party code. :) Someone forgot to set the super inside of viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear. I cannot see the super. viewWillDisappear(animated) call neither in your code. Can you give it a try?

Comment: I have added both and there is no difference in behavior. I should have the calls to super anyway, though. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer below, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you try to `present` a new viewController on a viewController which is going to be removed from the view hierarchy.

Maybe a dirty fix can be to replace:

```
self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController?.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: That does not work either - I think the scope would already be changed and I do not get the alert at all.